# Want to convert the csv file from line break mode to be separated by comma

Tags: python, csv

Currently the csv file is saved in line break mode. But it should be separated by comma for inputting these datas as an array.

The current csv file:

```
test@eaxmple.com
test@eaxmple.com
test@eaxmple.com
```

The ideal csv file:

```
test@eaxmple.com, test@eaxmple.com, test@eaxmple.com
```

The code:

```py
def get_addresses():
    with open('./addresses.csv') as f:
        addresses_file = csv.reader(f)
        # Need to be converted
```

How can I convert it? I hope to use Python.

tried this.

```py
with open('./addresses.txt') as input, open('./addresses.csv', 'w') as output:
    output.write(','.join(input.readlines()))
    output.write('\n')
```

the result:

```
test@eaxmple.com
,test@eaxmple.com
,test@eaxmple.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('./addresses.txt') as f:
   print(",".join(f.read().splitlines()))
```

Comment: The `[1:`] woud be necesary and useful if the input file had a header line; but the sample data in the question doesn't have one, so you will be omitting the first address.

Comment: I got this error `AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'splitlines'`

Comment: @k10a, i have updated my answer this should fix your error

Answer (score 1):

Load the original file into pandas using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv({YOUR_FILE}, escapechar='\\')
```

Then export it back to `.csv` (by default this will be comma separated).

```
df.to_csv({YOUR_FILE})
```

Comment: If the OP is using Pandas anyway, this makes sense, but for somebody only just learning Python with no intention to learn Pandas at this point, it's probably not a brilliant idea, and obscures the learning.

Comment: I see your point. However, Pandas is a basic and critical tool that anyone working with data using Python should learn. Besides, it's a simple line of code.

Comment: Pandas is popular and useful in data science etc, but pulling it in as a dependency e.g. for a simple GUI application which needs to read a CSV file would be quite excessive.

Comment: Agreed. If that was the case, then I would have never suggested this solution.

Answer (score 1):

For this simple task, just read them into an array, then join the array on commas.

```
with open('./addresses.txt') as input, open('./addresses.csv', 'w') as output:
    output.write(','.join(input.read().splitlines()))
    output.write('\n')
```

This ignores any complications in the CSV formatting - if your data could contain commas (which are reserved as the field separator) or double quotes (which are reserved for quoting other reserved characters) you will want to switch to the proper `csv` module for output and perhaps for input.

Overwriting your input file is also an unnecessary complication, so I suggest you rename the input file to `addresses.txt` and use `addresses.csv` only for output.

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/AdequateStunningVideogames

Another common trick is to read one line at a time, and write a separator before each output except the first. This is more scalable for large input files.

```
with open blah blah blah ...:
    separator = ''  # for first line
    for line in input:
        output.write(separator)
        output.write(line)
        separator = ','  # for subsequent input lines
    output.write('\n')
```

Comment: Tried. But they have blank line stilll.